# excel custom cell format that covers my simple cases

Tags: excel, format

I want to format some excel cells with bellow results.

```
   1        -> 1   
   123      -> 123  
   12345    -> 12,345  
   1.2      -> 1.2  
   1.234    -> 1.23  
   1234.567 -> 1,234.57
```

but can't find any format to cover all situations.
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you want the thousand separator to show, there is a setting in [excel number formats](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/show-or-hide-the-thousands-separator-b9f8aee0-ef50-42e5-8fd7-6e3ab1493876). This can also help you round your values as you've done on the last two rows.

Comment: Also [here is a solution](https://chandoo.org/wp/show-decimal-points-if-needed/) for showing decimals only if they are present using conditional formatting. This can be combined with the above if needed.

Comment: You can fix it through [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/show-or-hide-the-thousands-separator-b9f8aee0-ef50-42e5-8fd7-6e3ab1493876) or through Windows local settings on your control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Demo]

Presume your data is in range `A1:A8`,

Steps are:

1. Set the default format of your numbers to `General`;
2. Set up the following three **conditional formatting** rules:

`Rule 1`, to show the thousands separator for whole number:

```
=MOD($A1,1)=0
```

`Rule 2`, to show thousands separator and round the number to 2 decimal places if it has 2 or more decimal places:

```
=LEN(MOD($A1,1))>3
```

`Rule 3`, to show thousands separator and round the number to 1 decimal place if it has 1 decimal place:

```
=IFERROR(LEN($A1)-FIND(".",$A1),0)=1
```

> To use conditional formatting, highlight your data range with the first cell being the active cell, click **Conditional Formatting** button under your `Home` tab, select `New Rule...`, select the last option which is `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`, and enter the formula.
>
> Repeat this process to set up all three rules in the **exact order** as in my screenshot, `Rule 1` should be at the bottom in the Rules Manager while `Rule 3` must sit on top in the Rules Manager.